# AlgoExpert: Validate Subsequence, not passing all test cases

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

[image: AlgoExpert Question Prompt]

Question: Validate Subsequence on AlgoExpert. Given two non-empty arrays of integers write a function that determines whether the second array is a subsequence of the first one.

My code is not passing all test cases, what am I doing wrong?

```
public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    int sequenceIndex = 0;
    
    while(arrayIndex < array.size() && sequenceIndex < sequence.size()){
        if(array.get(arrayIndex).equals(sequence.get(sequenceIndex))){
            sequenceIndex++;
        } else {
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
    if(sequenceIndex == (sequence.size())){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You used the point raised in my answer, added it as your own, unaccepted my answer and accepted your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help!
Updated Solution:

```
  public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    int sequenceIndex = 0;
    
    while(arrayIndex < array.size() && sequenceIndex < sequence.size()){
        if(array.get(arrayIndex).equals(sequence.get(sequenceIndex))){
            sequenceIndex++;
            arrayIndex++;       
    } else {
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    if(sequenceIndex == (sequence.size())){
        return true;
    }
}
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have matched a character in both arrays, you should be moving both pointers instead of just one.

```
if(array.get(arrayIndex).equals(sequence.get(sequenceIndex))){
    sequenceIndex++;
}
arrayIndex++;
```

Comment: Yes, `arrayIndex++` should be executed without any condition, and thus `while` can be turned into good old `for`: `for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < array.size() && sequenceIndex < sequence.size(); arrayIndex++) if (array.get(arrayIndex).equals(sequence.get(sequenceIndex))) sequenceIndex++;`

Answer (score 0):

**This solution passed all the tests, cheer!**

> ```
>     import java.util.*;
>
> class Program {
>   public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
>     // Write your code here.
>     int k=0;
>     int truecounter=0;
>     int totalsize=sequence.size();
>     for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
>       if(k<totalsize){
>         int squencearray_value = sequence.get(k);
>         if(squencearray_value == array.get(i)){
>           truecounter=truecounter+1;
>           k++;
>         }
>       }else{
>         if(truecounter==totalsize)
>           return true;
>         else 
>           return false;
>     
>       }
>       
>     }
>
>      if(truecounter==totalsize)
>           return true;
>         else 
>           return false;
>     
>    // return false;
>   }
> }
> ```